# What are the main differences between uwot and umap packages in R?

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction, implementation

There are two packages in R that implement the UMAP algorithm for low-dimensional embedding ('uwot' and 'umap'). I've found they can give vastly different results for some datasets. For example, the embeddings below are of the same $4001$ equidistant points in $R^{4000}$.

[image]

In this case the 'umap' package seems to give a better gestalt of a set of equidistant points. On the other hand, in other cases such as the UMAP on Cartesian coordinates of 41K cities below, 'uwot' seems much better.

[image]

I was hoping someone could explain the main differences between these two implementations and give some general advice as to when to use which package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain the uwot package. It's an independent implementation of UMAP (although it relied strongly on me looking at the code of the "real" [Python UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) package during its development).

The umap R package also has its own independent implementation of UMAP (the default) or can use the Python UMAP if it's available to your R environment. I am not sure which approach produced the results above, though.

The first result from uwot certainly looks odd. My strong suspicion would be that the nearest neighbor routine used by uwot ([Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) via the [RcppAnnoy package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppAnnoy)) is failing due to the rather high dimensionality of the input data. I am not sure how the umap R package calculates the nearest neighbors but I don't think it uses Annoy, so that might explain the difference.

The difference in the second result might be due to differences in initialization. Very hard to say though.

Although I am unable to answer your question here, if you are willing to [open an issue](https://github.com/jlmelville/uwot/issues) at the uwot issue tracker with details of how the input data was generated and how uwot was run I can investigate the problem with the first result.